# How to convert this PromiseResult Object to an Array?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've successfully retrieved a promise from this async/await function:

```
  const fetchJSON= (async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/getJavaMaps')
      return await response.json()
  })();
```

Now I want to convert or assign the result to an array. This is what the result looks like in the console.log(fetchJSON):

```
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
One: "Batman"
Three: "Superman"
Two: "Ironman"
```

However when I perform operations like:
console.log(fetchJSON.One);
console.log(fetchJSON.length);

I always get:

```
undefined
```

I've tried this:

```
 let myarray = Object.entries(fetchJSON);
```

But it doesnt convert the PromiseResult Object to 2d arrays.

Comment: You need to await the Promise object.

Answer (score 3):

All asynchronous functions must be resolved using the `await` statement or `then` chain. You cannot get the result of an asynchronous function in synchronous code.

```
(async()=>{
   const arr= await fetchJSON();
})();
```

Comment: I know this is old, but this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You made fetchJSON to a function.
Thus the return will not go back to fetchJSON. You have to handle it like this:

```
let myResult;
fetchJSON()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        myResult =  result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

or

```
    let myResult = async fetchJSON()
                       .catch((error) => {
                             console.log(error);
                             });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myResult));
```

Unhandled promises are already deprecated. Don't just async/await! Catch your errors!
You have at least a catch-block to handle errors.